# Remove Rows from Multiple Tables with Join

Tags: mysql, join, sql-delete, multiple-tables

I'm trying to remove rows from multiple tables that are connected. But when I run the stored procedure 0 rows are affected. As you can see the function is quite extensive but the idea is that it shall delete rows from many tables, that are connected.

How can I make this work?

```
CREATE DEFINER=`root`@`localhost` PROCEDURE `remove_tables_select1`(
    IN in_TableA_ID INT
    )
BEGIN   
    DELETE FROM TableB, TableC, TableD, TableE, TableA, TableF, TableG, TableH, TableI
    using TableB 
    inner join TableC on (TableC.ID = TableB.TableC_ID)
    inner join TableH on (TableH.TableB_ID = TableB.ID)
    inner join TableD on (TableD.TableB_ID = TableB.ID) 
    inner join TableE on (TableE.TableB_ID = TableB.ID) 
    inner join TableA on (TableA.ID = in_TableA_ID)
    inner join TableF on (TableF.TableA_ID = TableA.ID)
    inner join TableG on (TableG.TableA_ID = TableA.ID)
    inner join TableI on (TableI.TableH_ID = TableH.ID);
END
```

A smaller example:

```
CREATE DEFINER=`root`@`localhost` PROCEDURE `remove_tables_select1`(
    IN in_TableA_ID INT
    )
BEGIN   
    DELETE FROM TableA, TableB, TableC, TableD
    using TableA 
    inner join TableB on (TableB.ID = TableA.TableB_ID)
    inner join TableC on (TableC.TableB_ID = TableC.ID)
    inner join TableD on (TableC.TableD_ID = TableD.ID)
    WHERE TableA.ID = in_TableA_ID;
END
```

Comment: Check that the corresponding SELECT query returns records.

Answer (score 0):

For your smaller example, try to use next query -

```
DELETE a, b, c, d FROM TableA a
JOIN TableB b
  ON b.ID = a.TableB_ID
JOIN TableC c
  ON c.TableB_ID = c.ID
JOIN TableD d
  ON c.TableD_ID = d.ID
WHERE
  a.ID = in_TableA_ID;
```

Note, that INNER JOIN is used; check that corresponding SELECT query returns records.

Answer (score 0):

This might introduce some overhead, but think over using `CASCADE` deletion for [FOREING KEYS](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.1/en/innodb-foreign-key-constraints.html).